# Fixed element at end of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am searching a lot but don't know how to name it properly.

Idea:

We have two divs together. The first one on the left have a lot of content, more than the one on right side. The second one have only form to be filled up and send. When user scrolls the left div for more information, the right side with contact form will follow to the end of this div. And when user scrolls up, this form on the right will follow it too.

How to detect it? Is there any framework?

I have a lot of divs in website and each one must have this script.

Screen to show what I mean:

[image: SCREEN]

Link to page:

[LINK](http://www.contman.pl/kariera/?page_id=58)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the right `div` scrolls to? If so, try `position:fixed` if not, please explain more. And please **Add your code or, even better, provide a link a post a working demo using [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or something**.

Comment: @MoshFeu exactly no, the right div don't scroll and i want to force it. I tried with position: fixed but not working form me. I will add a link to this page in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following links:

1. http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-To-Fix-Element-Within-Its-Parent-Container-nail.html
   Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Fix-Element-Within-Its-Parent-Container-nail/
2. http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Super-Tiny-jQuery-Plugin-For-Sticky-Elements-Sticky.html
   Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Super-Tiny-jQuery-Plugin-For-Sticky-Elements-Sticky/
3. http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Multipurpose-jQuery-Sticky-Sidebar-Plugin-scrollWith.html
   Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multipurpose-jQuery-Sticky-Sidebar-Plugin-scrollWith/scrollwith-single-first.html

Comment: You need to set the second div's css property `"position: fixed"` as other users have already suggested you. You can download the sample from links i've provide to take help if you don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `position: fixed;` for the right side.

Comment: Is the result as you expect? http://codepen.io/tunguyen/pen/JKamNN.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want. the concept is to use `position:fixed` and `right:0` and/or `top:10px` properties with your css. this is a small example for it.hope this will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
 body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
 }

.right{
 width: 30%;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: gray;
}

.check{
 position: absolute;
 top: 900px;

}
</style>

<body>

<div class="right">
 <h2>send an email</h2>
</div>

<h1 class="check">checkin the view</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

values are to get an idea, change those as your need.